# Can somebody help me uploading to postimg with Curl?

Tags: curl

They've disabled http://old.postimage.org so I have to use https://postimg.io/upload.php

Been using this before:

```
curl -F "upload=@cache\cover_art.jpg;filename=cover_art.jpg" -F "adult=no" "https://old.postimage.org/"
```

but it's not working anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the look of it the following will work :

```sh
curl -F "Filedata=@cover_art.jpg;filename=cover_art.jpg;type=image/jpeg;" \
     -F "token=61aa06d6116f7331ad7b2ba9c7fb707ec9b182e8" \
     -F "upload_session=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
     -F "adult=0" "https://postimage.io/upload.php"
```

This gives a JSON result like :

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "total_uploaded": 1,
    "url": "\/\/postimg.org\/image\/4crb2b603\/9bfe3a80\/"
}
```

If you look at the https://postimage.io/ page you will find this :

```
var upload_session = rand_string(32);
```

It seems the server checks for exactly 32 characters for the `upload_session` so : `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`.

The variable `token` seems to be hardcoded (same for different request / IP / UA). Maybe it changes periodically or depending on other parameters so you can scrap it for instance using [gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/):

```sh
curl -s "https://postimage.io/" | \
     gawk 'match($0, /'\''token'\''\s+:\s+'\''(.*)'\''/, data) {print data[1]}'
```

or with grep :

```sh
curl -s "https://postimage.io/" |  grep -oP "'token'\s+:\s+'\K(\w+)"
```

So the following script would work using curl, grep and [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) (JSON parser), it returns the generated uri value :

```sh
token=$(curl -s "https://postimage.io/" |  grep -oP "'token'\s+:\s+'\K(\w+)")

curl -s -F "Filedata=@cover_art.jpg;filename=cover_art.jpg;type=image/jpeg;" \
        -F "token=$token" \
        -F "upload_session=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
        -F "adult=0" "https://postimage.io/upload.php" | \
        jq -r '"https:" + .url'
```